# IN() not working in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `employee`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `selectemployeebyids`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectemployeebyids`(IN empid VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT empname,salary,department from emp where empid IN (empid) ORDER BY empid;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

can anyone please help me

With Regards

Manju K

Comment: `IN` doesn't accept a string with comma separated values, it just accepts comma separated values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying lot i find instead of `IN()`, `FIND_IN_SET()` works for me.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `employee`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `selectemployeebyids`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectemployeebyids`(IN empid VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT empname,salary,department from emp where empid FIND_IN_SET(empid) ORDER BY empid;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: When posting code, please highlight it and hit the `{}` code button (or indent code lines by four spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$ 

USE `employee`$$ 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `selectemployeebyids`$$ 

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectemployeebyids`(IN empid_in VARCHAR(100)) 
BEGIN 
    SELECT empname,salary,department from emp 
        where concat(',',empid_in,',') like concat('%,'cast  (empid as varchar(10)),',%')
        ORDER BY empid; 
   END$$ 


 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Actually by the above procedure i want to retrive empname , salary , department from employee table whose employee id is 101,102,103 and 104

Comment: @Madhivanan: it's terrible solution which will lead to fullscan

Comment: @zerkms, then you need a table valued split function and join with the original table